# Pyinstaller – How to call python from node.js subprocess in executable?

Tags: python, node.js, flask, subprocess, pyinstaller

I have developed an application which I would like to convert to an executable file (.exe) on Windows. It uses a python-based backend (Python 3.9) and a node.js/react frontend. Running the programm in my conda environment works nicely as expected. For the conversion to the executable I used pyinstaller with the onedir option and defined a corresponding .spec file. The conversion itself works, however the following error occurs when starting the .exe file:

```
> reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0 backend C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\app_frontend\dist\start_app
[1] > set FLASK_ENV=development && set FLASK_DEBUG=True && python run.py
[1]
[1] Python konnte nicht gefunden werden. F�hren Sie die Verkn�pfung ohne Argumente aus, um sie �ber den Microsoft Store zu installieren, oder deaktivieren Sie diese Verkn�pfung unter npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! errno 9009
[1] npm ERR! reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0 backend: `set FLASK_ENV=development && set FLASK_DEBUG=True && python run.py`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 9009
[1] npm ERR!
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0 backend script.
[1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[1] npm ERR!     C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-19T08_16_57_264Z-debug.log
[1] npm run backend exited with code 9009
[0] i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://10.145.133.56/
[0] i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
```

Pyinstaller converts the python file `start_app.py` which calls subprocess, which executes the following lines:

```
import subprocess
if __name__=='__main__':
    command = "npm run start"
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

The `npm start`command is defined in the script section of a package.json file, which looks the following:

```
{
  "name": "reactcomponentsapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"set PORT=8000 && react-scripts start\" \"npm run backend\"",
    "backend": "set FLASK_ENV=development && set FLASK_DEBUG=True && python run.py",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },...
```

`run.py` creates a Flask app:

```
from backend import create_app    
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = create_app()
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0',
                port=app.config['PORT'],
                threaded=True,
                )
```

with `backend.__init`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = None

def create_app():
    global app
    if not app:
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config.from_object('config')
        app.static_folder = app.config.get('STATIC_FOLDER')
    from . import views
    CORS(app)
    return app
```

To conclude, the python script, calls npm in a subprocess, which again calls python.
As the `sys.executable` is set to the path of `start_app.exe` and no python executable exists, python is not found. Replacing `python run.py` with the path of the python executable of my conda environment works. However, this is obviously not an option as the executable should be distributed without installing python.

Can I somehow set a correct python variable/call it correctly?

**Edit:**

Output of the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'backend'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.14
3 info using node@v14.17.5
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebackend', 'backend', 'postbackend' ]
5 info lifecycle reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0~prebackend: reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0~backend: reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0~backend: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0~backend: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\app_frontend\dist\start_app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\myuserPycharmProjects\app_frontend\dist\start_app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\myuser\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.312.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CaseWare IDEA\IDEA\Lib\site-packages\pypiwin32_system32;C:\Program Files\CaseWare IDEA\IDEA;C:\Program Files (x86)\CaseWare IDEA\IDEA;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Azure Data Studio\bin;
9 verbose lifecycle reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0~backend: CWD: C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\app_frontend\dist\start_app
10 silly lifecycle reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0~backend: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'set FLASK_ENV=development && set FLASK_DEBUG=True && python run.py'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0~backend: Returned: code: 9009  signal: null
12 info lifecycle reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0~backend: Failed to exec backend script
13 verbose stack Error: reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0 backend: `set FLASK_ENV=development && set FLASK_DEBUG=True && python run.py`
13 verbose stack Exit status 9009
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\myuserPycharmProjects\app_frontend\dist\start_app
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "backend"
18 verbose node v14.17.5
19 verbose npm  v6.14.14
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 9009
22 error reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0 backend: `set FLASK_ENV=development && set FLASK_DEBUG=True && python run.py`
22 error Exit status 9009
23 error Failed at the reactcomponentsapp@0.1.0 backend script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 9009, true ]
```

Comment: So you have python env on this OS, why not use just python process instead exe?

Comment: I would like to share it with non-technical users with Windows OS. Therefore the need to convert it to .exe @ElapsedSoul

Comment: get a python installed folder with the app.

Comment: error suggest to check log file for details. Did you check it?

Comment: @furas: Yes, see the edit for the output

Answer (score 0):

U have to include all the node script related dependencies Files as --add-data into the --onefile or --onedir method. Also include

below code , if your are referring to any file location. In frozen app the path is either `/temp/_MEIPASSXX` or the app.exe path. So you need to refer the file locations if used.

```
import sys
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    print('running in a PyInstaller bundle')
else:
    print('running in a normal Python process')
```